Fill NAs when you have zeros in your dataset
Suppose you have the following dataframe:
df <- data.frame(year=c(rep(2010,12),rep(2011,12),rep(2012,12)),
                country=c(rep("DEU",4),rep("ITA",4),rep("USA",4),
                          rep("DEU",4),rep("ITA",4),rep("USA",4),
                          rep("DEU",4),rep("ITA",4),rep("USA",4)),
                industry=c(rep(1:4,9)),
                stock1=c(rep(0,24),0,0,2,4,1,0,1,2,3,3,3,5),
                stock2=c(rep(0,24),0,3,3,4,5,0,1,1,2,2,2,5))

and you want to get the following outcome:
df2 <- data.frame(year=c(rep(2010,12),rep(2011,12),rep(2012,12)),
                 country=c(rep("DEU",4),rep("ITA",4),rep("USA",4),
                           rep("DEU",4),rep("ITA",4),rep("USA",4),
                           rep("DEU",4),rep("ITA",4),rep("USA",4)),
                 industry=c(rep(1:4,9)),
                 stock1=c(rep(NA,24),0,0,2,4,1,0,1,2,3,3,3,5),
                 stock2=c(rep(NA,24),0,3,3,4,5,0,1,1,2,2,2,5))


The concept is that if, for a particular year, a specific country reports zeros in stock2 across ALL industries, then those zeros should be replaced with NAs (Not Available) in both stock1 and stock2. My attempt below
library(dplyr)
df2 = df %>%
  group_by(country, year, industry) %>%
  mutate(
    stock1 = ifelse(all(stock2 == 0), NA, stock1),
    stock2 = ifelse(all(stock2 == 0), NA, stock2)
  )


Thanks!

You can try this approach:
df %>% 
  mutate(
    ind = all(stock2==0),
    across(stock1:stock2, ~if_else(ind, NA,.)),
    .by = c(year, country)) %>% select(-ind)

To avoid the temporary ind column (used to ensure if_else() TRUE and FALSE have same length, you can use case_when() as a shortcut:
mutate(
  df,
  across(stock1:stock2, ~case_when(all(stock2==0)==F~.)),
  .by = c(year, country)
)

Borrowing @shaun_m excellent little trick, you can also use if_else() by setting FALSE to 1, and multiplying:
mutate(
  df,
  mutate(across(stock1:stock2, ~if_else(all(stock2==0), NA,1)*.),
  .by = c(year, country)
)

All give same output

There is an issue with group_by(country, year, industry) because it groups at the individual row, where you want to look across all industries, so it should be group_by(country, year).
ifelse(all(....)) returns a result of length 1 so I also had to change the code in the mutate a bit to stop it recycling the first row in each country * year group.
df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(country, year) %>%
  mutate(
    stock1 = ifelse(all(stock1 == 0), NA, 1) * stock1,
    stock2 = ifelse(all(stock2 == 0), NA, 1) * stock2
  )


nice trick.. I added that alternative to my answer.

df |>
  mutate(
    stock1 = if (all(stock2 == 0)) NA_real_ else stock1,
    stock2 = if (all(stock2 == 0)) NA_real_ else stock2,
    .by = c(country, year)
  )

